# Waiting event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming

I can't understand why the waiting event is not firing.

Basically I want the animation in the container to work whenever the video buffers.

Is there any other event that I need to look out for?

```js
function play() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<video onwaiting="play()" controls autoplay>
   <source src = "bleach-cool-mp3.webm" type="video/webm" >
</video>
<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: have a look at this example; https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onwaiting the reason why your code is not doing anything is because it is meant as an action when the video is done playing. What you are lookiing for is to wait until the page is ready and fire play() function when document is ready

Comment: @Ggg not following you mate. How is my code different from the one you are pointing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two important things:

**First**: You can't name your function `play()`, because is a [*reserved keyword*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) for the video api, you have to rename it

**Second**: Your `onwaiting` event is working fine, but it only triggers when your video has to buff the next frames (like slow connection problems). If you want it to trigger when the video is searching for the data to show, like the first loading, use `onloadstart` event:

Bellow, your working snippet:

```js
function PlayAnimation() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<video onwaiting="PlayAnimation()" onloadstart="PlayAnimation()" controls autoplay>
   <source src = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i want it to fire when it buffers too so do i just add an onwaiting calling the same fn

Comment: Sure @akshaykishore! Use both of events handler `onwaiting` and `onloadstart`, don't forget to mark que question as answer if helped you ;)